# Need Sha1 encryption in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sha1

I have sha1 encryption coding in php

```
<?php
echo hash('sha1', 'testing'.'abcdb');
?>
```

but, my requirement should have to run the page xyz.html, so the above block is not working.

So, I need to do sha1 encryption in jquery/javascript.  Help me by providing coding for sha1 encryption.

***this is exactly have to be converted to scripts***

```
'<?php echo hash('sha1', 'my-secret-key' . $_REQUEST["email"]); ?>'
```

Comment: sha1 isn't an ecryption. Better think of it as a lossy compression.

Comment: its not working, i have to convert "'<?php echo hash('sha1', 'my-secret-key' . $_REQUEST["email"]); ?>'" to scripts

Comment: @itsme You *do* realize that your key won't be secret if you have it in javascript, right? What isn't working? What do you get? What do you expect? Do you get an error? A wrong value?

Comment: If you're encrypting someone on the client side, you're doing it wrongly. The client should not receive the encryption key at the first place. The best way is to place an AJAX call to the server, which receives the content (i.e. the email address), and returns the hashed/encrypted content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this, you can either use AJAX to call up your PHP page and retrieve the SHA-1.

Or, you could use one of the JS libraries, such as CryptoJS.

Comment: its not working, i have to convert "'<?php echo hash('sha1', 'my-secret-key' . $_REQUEST["email"]); ?>'" to scripts

Comment: I meant, put the "'<?php echo hash('sha1', 'my-secret-key' . $_REQUEST["email"]); ?>" code to a separate PHP file, and then call this PHP file via AJAX.

Answer (score 8):

Just google it and found: http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1/

```
function sha1(str) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1/
  // original by: Webtoolkit.info (http://www.webtoolkit.info/)
  // improved by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //  depends on: utf8_encode
  //   example 1: sha1('Kevin van Zonneveld');
  //   returns 1: '54916d2e62f65b3afa6e192e6a601cdbe5cb5897'

  var rotate_left = function(n, s) {
    var t4 = (n << s) | (n >>> (32 - s));
    return t4;
  };

  /*var lsb_hex = function (val) { // Not in use; needed?
    var str="";
    var i;
    var vh;
    var vl;

    for ( i=0; i<=6; i+=2 ) {
      vh = (val>>>(i*4+4))&0x0f;
      vl = (val>>>(i*4))&0x0f;
      str += vh.toString(16) + vl.toString(16);
    }
    return str;
  };*/

  var cvt_hex = function(val) {
    var str = '';
    var i;
    var v;

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
      v = (val >>> (i * 4)) & 0x0f;
      str += v.toString(16);
    }
    return str;
  };

  var blockstart;
  var i, j;
  var W = new Array(80);
  var H0 = 0x67452301;
  var H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
  var H2 = 0x98BADCFE;
  var H3 = 0x10325476;
  var H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
  var A, B, C, D, E;
  var temp;

  str = this.utf8_encode(str);
  var str_len = str.length;

  var word_array = [];
  for (i = 0; i < str_len - 3; i += 4) {
    j = str.charCodeAt(i) << 24 | str.charCodeAt(i + 1) << 16 | str.charCodeAt(i + 2) << 8 | str.charCodeAt(i + 3);
    word_array.push(j);
  }

  switch (str_len % 4) {
    case 0:
      i = 0x080000000;
      break;
    case 1:
      i = str.charCodeAt(str_len - 1) << 24 | 0x0800000;
      break;
    case 2:
      i = str.charCodeAt(str_len - 2) << 24 | str.charCodeAt(str_len - 1) << 16 | 0x08000;
      break;
    case 3:
      i = str.charCodeAt(str_len - 3) << 24 | str.charCodeAt(str_len - 2) << 16 | str.charCodeAt(str_len - 1) <<
        8 | 0x80;
      break;
  }

  word_array.push(i);

  while ((word_array.length % 16) != 14) {
    word_array.push(0);
  }

  word_array.push(str_len >>> 29);
  word_array.push((str_len << 3) & 0x0ffffffff);

  for (blockstart = 0; blockstart < word_array.length; blockstart += 16) {
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      W[i] = word_array[blockstart + i];
    }
    for (i = 16; i <= 79; i++) {
      W[i] = rotate_left(W[i - 3] ^ W[i - 8] ^ W[i - 14] ^ W[i - 16], 1);
    }

    A = H0;
    B = H1;
    C = H2;
    D = H3;
    E = H4;

    for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
      temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + ((B & C) | (~B & D)) + E + W[i] + 0x5A827999) & 0x0ffffffff;
      E = D;
      D = C;
      C = rotate_left(B, 30);
      B = A;
      A = temp;
    }

    for (i = 20; i <= 39; i++) {
      temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0x6ED9EBA1) & 0x0ffffffff;
      E = D;
      D = C;
      C = rotate_left(B, 30);
      B = A;
      A = temp;
    }

    for (i = 40; i <= 59; i++) {
      temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + ((B & C) | (B & D) | (C & D)) + E + W[i] + 0x8F1BBCDC) & 0x0ffffffff;
      E = D;
      D = C;
      C = rotate_left(B, 30);
      B = A;
      A = temp;
    }

    for (i = 60; i <= 79; i++) {
      temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0xCA62C1D6) & 0x0ffffffff;
      E = D;
      D = C;
      C = rotate_left(B, 30);
      B = A;
      A = temp;
    }

    H0 = (H0 + A) & 0x0ffffffff;
    H1 = (H1 + B) & 0x0ffffffff;
    H2 = (H2 + C) & 0x0ffffffff;
    H3 = (H3 + D) & 0x0ffffffff;
    H4 = (H4 + E) & 0x0ffffffff;
  }

  temp = cvt_hex(H0) + cvt_hex(H1) + cvt_hex(H2) + cvt_hex(H3) + cvt_hex(H4);
  return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

call

```
sha1('testing'+'abcdb');
```

Comment: The link to the original website does not responds at this time.

Comment: @AnwarNairi And thats why we do need SO =)

Comment: Right ! Also I saw Locutus.js implementing this function, any relation with this library and phpjs ?

Comment: There is a web standard supported in modern browsers that you can use instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030304/772035

Comment: Would you trust some random code off OS for anything serious crypto-related? If no, better use an audited library or a sndardized method like the one @Paul suggested.