# How can I encript string to SHA-1 using javascript OR jquery?

Tags: javascript

I want to hash a simple string with SHA-1 hash function using javascript.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: SHA-1 is a one-way hash function, not an encryption function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It sounds like you may want help with homework.  May I suggest, reviewing this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 13):

In a browser, you can use [SubtleCrypto.digest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest), which returns a Promise:

```
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', arrayBuffer);
```

In node.js you can use [crypto.createHash](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options):

```
const crypto = require( 'crypto' );
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
const result = hash.digest(buffer);
```

Browser demo:

```js
logSha1( 'foobar' );

async function logSha1( str ) {
  const buffer = new TextEncoder( 'utf-8' ).encode( str );
  const digest = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', buffer);

  // Convert digest to hex string
  const result = Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest)).map( x => x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0') ).join('');

  console.log( result );
}
```

Comment: I thought the SO policy was to not encourage such absolutely zero-effort, "gimme code" questions by providing answers.

Comment: Is there a way to create string with radix 36 or at least 32 instead of 16? I'm really confused with the padding magic you do when converting to hex.

Comment: @icl7126 It's not as easy to go to other bases. The easiest thing may be to get the hex using the answer above and then use another snippet to do the conversion from hex to another base. That said, this should work for Base 32 (A-Z2-7): `const result = Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest)).flatMap( x => x.toString(2).padStart(8,'0').split('') ).join('').match( /(.{5})/g ).map( x => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567'[parseInt( x, 2 )] ).join('');`. It works by converting the array to individual bits and the grouping them into chunks of 5 and looking up the appropriate Base32 character.

Comment: @icl7126 You may need to shim `Array#flatMap` or replace it with [reduce and concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative) if you want more browser support.

Comment: The padding is just to add leading zeroes. `num.toString(16)` returns a hex string in JavaScript, but if you want to always have two hex digits you need a padStart. `10..toString(16) === 'a'`, but `10..toString(16).padStart(2,'0') === '0a'`.

Comment: Similarly in the comment for Base32 we want to represent the byte as 8 individual bits instead of two hex chars. `10..toString(2) === '1010'`, but `10..toString(2).padStart(8,'0') === '00001010'`.

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now.

Comment: You're welcome @icl7126