# Is there any way to access a JS variable in PHP within the same file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

I have this html file which I am using to encrypt a string to sha1 hash. I receive the string like "1 | 2 | 3" from a javascript function (I haven't shown the function below), and I need to replace the | with - and then encrypt the modified string. Here's the code I have built so far -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test;
    var value;
    var message = "1 | 2 | 3";
    test = message.split(' | ');
    value = "<?php $final = test[0] . " - " . test[1] . " - " . test[2]; echo sha1($final);?>";
    alert(value);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*I came to know about posting the value to another PHP file using HTML form, and accessing it through `$_POST`/`$_GET` - but my app won't allow for 2 files; hence I am trying to combine it all in one html file...*

---

PHP has a in-built SHA1 encryption function, but javascript doesn't - the `value` variable in the above code is broken; how do I pass a variable to PHP from JS and back from PHP to JS? Again, I just want to modify (encrypt it) a JS variable using PHP and then set the PHP modified variable's value to a new JS variable. What should I do? Please guide :)

Comment: Hurdle 1: javascript is executed in the browser, PHP on the server

Comment: @JonP - thanks for replying. So is it not possible then?

Comment: Just hash in js : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099292/need-sha1-encryption-in-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to javascript variable like that. PHP is executed by the server and JavaScript by the client. You can create an ajax function in JS that call your PHP script.

Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

**JS**

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       xhttp.responseText // return from your PHP;
    }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET", "yourphp.php?variable="+yourjsvariable, true);
 xhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?PHP

return $_GET["variable"]; 

?>
```